# Objective-C, iPad: DetailView only displays the value from the first row when filtering

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, master-detail, didselectrowatindexpath

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for any responses.

I'm making an iPad app, which is a MasterDetail View. The table displays a list of names (Keys from an NSDictionary) and the Detail View displays an image associated to each Name (the Value from the NSDictionary). The table contains a search to filter the names.

Lets say a Dictionary @{@"John":@"Star.png", @"Mary":@"Circle.png"}. John is in the first position of the table, so when that first row is selected a Star image is displayed. Mary is in the second position and when that row is selected a Circle displayed.

The problem:
Now if I filter and search for Mary, that name will occupy the first row. If I select the row, a Star will display instead of a Circle.

Code below:

The dictionary and arrays for indexing

```
attendees =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flake1.png"],@"John",[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flake2.png"],@"Mary",[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flake3.png"], @"Bob", nil];

keys = [attendees allKeys];
values = [attendees allValues];
```

The didSelectRow

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (isSearching && [filteredList count]) {
    //If the user is searching, use the list in our filteredList array.
    detailViewController.title = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.detailLabel.text = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.tablePicture.image = values[indexPath.row];
} else {
    detailViewController.title = keys[indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.detailLabel.text = keys[indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.tablePicture.image = values[indexPath.row];
```

The Filtering

```
- (void)filterListForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
{
[filteredList removeAllObjects]; //clears the array from all the string objects it might contain from the previous searches

for (NSString *title in attendees) {
    NSRange nameRange = [title rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        [filteredList addObject:title];
    }
}
}
```

My guess is that the issue is caused by the filter. Am I right? Any suggestions or need additional info? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value used is not correct when filtered.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (isSearching && [filteredList count]) {
      //If the user is searching, use the list in our filteredList array.
     detailViewController.title = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     detailViewController.detailLabel.text = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     detailViewController.tablePicture.image = [attendees valueForKey:filteredList[indexPath.row]]; //Use this line instead
}
```

Comment: That's what I figured, wasn't sure the best way to handle it. I'll try this tonight once I get home from work and report back my results right after. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of having as a different array, fetch it from your dictionary. Updated my answer.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I actually kept everything else as is and just adjust that one line. I'm sure there are ways to optimize what I currently have. For now though, this will do.

Answer (score 0):

**edited**

The only problem I see in your code is how you fetch the value:

Instead of

`detailViewController.tablePicture.image = values[indexPath.row];`,

Do this:

```
detailViewController.tablePicture.image = [attendees valueForKey:detailViewController.detailLabel.text];
```